# Translate RSA verification algorithm from NodeJS to .Net Core for biometric data

Tags: node.js, .net, rsa

I'm trying to replicate a third-party NodeJS algorithm in .Net Core to verify a RSA payload and signature. The algorithm is used by a mobile app to verify biometric data. This is the thir-party NodeJS code:

```
import NodeRSA from "node-rsa";

export const verifySignature = (
  base64Signature: string,
  payload: string,
  publicKey: string
): boolean => {
  const key = new NodeRSA();
  const publicKeyBuffer = Buffer.from(publicKey, "base64");
  const signer = key.importKey(publicKeyBuffer, "pkcs8-public-der");

  return key.verify(Buffer.from(payload), base64Signature, "utf8", "base64");
};
```

The `publicKey` is a base64 string coming from a database, `base64signature` and `payload` come from the body on an API call. I asked to the third-party developer some `base64signature` and `payload` which works on his code, but I can't make them work with my .Net function:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

private bool VerifySignature(string base64Signature, string payload, string publicKey)
{
    RSA rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey), out _);
    return rsa.VerifyData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload), Convert.FromBase64String(base64Signature), HashAlgorithmName.MD5, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
}
```

I have no idea where is the error, maybe the `HashAlgorithmName.MD5` or the `RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1` parameters? I have no access to the mobile app code, so I don't know which paramters to use.

Any suggestion?

Thank you,
Sebasthian

Comment: When not sure, read the specification!!! MD5's collision resistance has been broken ages ago, so that was a pretty bad guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation of Node-RSA](https://github.com/rzcoder/node-rsa#options):

> `signingScheme` — scheme used for signing and verifying. Can be `'pkcs1'` or `'pss'` or `'scheme-hash'` format string (eg `'pss-sha1'`). **Default `'pkcs1-sha256'`**, or, if chosen pss: `'pss-sha1'`.